# Iptables to allow incoming FTP

Tags: iptables, ftp, vsftpd, file-transfer

I want to allow incoming FTP traffic.

CentOS 5.4:

This is my `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Thu Oct  3 21:23:07 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [133:14837]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct  3 21:23:07 2013
```

Also, by default, ip_conntrack_netbios_n module is getting loaded.

```
#service iptables restart

Flushing firewall rules:                                   [  OK  ]
Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter                    [  OK  ]
Unloading iptables modules:                                [  OK  ]
Applying iptables firewall rules:                          [  OK  ]
Loading additional iptables modules: ip_conntrack_netbios_n[  OK  ]
```

But the problem is not with that module, as I tried unloading it and still no luck.

If I disable iptables, I am able to transfer my backup from another machine to FTP.
If iptables is enforcing, then transfer failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding NEW fixed it, I believe.

Now, my iptables file look like this..

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Thu Oct  3 22:25:54 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [824:72492]

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 20:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 20:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct  3 22:25:54 2013
```

Typing it as answer, since too many characters are not allowed in comment.. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Cool it worked and glad I pointed you to the right direction. Please mark your own answer as solved so you help other people who seek for the right answer.

Comment: I believe there is a typo in the accepted answer. I believe that `--dport 20:65535` is leaving all ports from 20 - 65535 open from any source port between 1024:65535, which leaves many services exposed that probably shouldn't be, unless explicitly allowed. I believe what was intended is `--dport 1024:65535`

Answer (score 30):

Your ftp server needs a channel to transfer data. Port `21` is used to establish the connection. So to make data transfer possible you'd need to enable port `20` as well. See the following configuraton

First load the following module to make sure passive ftp connections are not rejected

```
modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
```

Allow FTP connections on port `21` incoming and outgoing

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,NEW -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 21"
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 21"
```

Allow FTP port `20` for active connections incoming and outgoing

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 20"
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 20"
```

Finally allow FTP passive inbound traffic

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow passive inbound connections"
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow passive inbound connections"
```

For more on FTP and firewall problems see: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html#active

*Edit:* Added `NEW` to the port 21 input rule.

Comment: I forgot to mention that  `--sport 1024: and --dport 1024:` mean that we are including all ports in the range  `1024:32535` which are unprivileged ports, meaning that users with no privilege access can use these ports to test their applications.

Comment: @Being Gokul, That's correct. We can control our server on what ports it should listen for client connections. However in a passive mode, we must use `--sport` to be an unprivileged mode to privent firewall problems and let clients connect to the server.

Comment: Still no luck. Have a doubt. --ctstate ESTABLISHED ... does it allow new connections? should we modify it by saying ESTABLISHED,NEW ?

Comment: Well, you can add `NEW,ESTABLISHED` but that shouldn't matter. A connection is first always in a `NEW` state then it jumps to `RELATED` which indicates that this connection is related to an already permitted connection. When the connection changes to `ESTABLISHED` state it informs us that a connection has been established on both sides (server / client). You might try `-m state --state ...` instead.

Comment: Please check the answer by me and let me know if rules are correct. Thank you so much.

Comment: your 2nd rule is missing a `tcp` after the first `-m`

Comment: The `NEW` does indeed matter. It doesn't seem to work without it.

Comment: @val0x00ff I don't understand the need for `--sport 1024:`. Why would the client's port be useful for the rule? If he connects from a port 80 to the server's passive ports, he must be allowed to connect too.

Answer (score 22):

I saw such extensive rules already in several Blogs etc. and wondered why not simply use

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

together with the `nf_conntrack_ftp` module. This is more concise and readable, which is generally a good thing, especially with firewalls...

FWIW, it seems that there was a change in kernel 4.7, so that you either need to set `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper=1` via `sysctl` (e.g. put it in `/etc/sysctl.d/conntrack.conf`) or use

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp --dport 21 -j CT --helper ftp
```

(see [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1369489) for more details)

Comment: The info about kernel 4.7 saved my life, was trying for hours to get this to work. A simple `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper` and everything works as expected.

Comment: Great! 4.7 was problem I could not resolve on Jessie kernel 4.9!

Comment: @Jakob there's an issue with RELATED connections that may be used to access other services: http://home.regit.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/secure-conntrack-helpers.html and https://github.com/rtsisyk/linux-iptables-contrack-exploit

Comment: you are the man!

Answer (score 9):

**FTP Client:**

```
lsmod | grep ftp
modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp
lsmod | grep ftp
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

**FTP SERVER:**

```
lsmod | grep ftp
modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp
lsmod | grep ftp
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

To toggle between passive and active mode on the client side

```
ftp> passive
Passive mode on.
ftp> passive
Passive mode off.
```

Comment: You definitely deserve some upvotes for this.  Forgetting to load the nf_conntrack_ftp module is a source of headaches when troubleshooting passive FTP connections and iptables connection tracking.  Using this module allows you to remove the "NEW" type so that these ports are protected from arbitrary connections without a previous FTP session being established.

Answer (score 1):

If you need both active and passive connections, and already accept `ESTABLISHED` connections, such as:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Then you only need to open port 21 and add a special rule for passive ports. No rule is needed for port 20 as it's already accepted by the `ESTABLISHED` rule above.

First accept new connections on `port 21`:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

Then add the CT helper for passive ports `1024:`:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp --dport 21 -j CT --helper ftp
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED -m helper --helper ftp --dport 1024: -j ACCEPT
```

See also:

- https://github.com/rtsisyk/linux-iptables-contrack-exploit
- http://home.regit.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/secure-conntrack-helpers.html

**Note:** you must set the `1024:` as in your FTP server: search for the default passive ports in your FTP configuration. Else you'd open too many ports that may not be FTP relative.

**Important note:** I didn't add `OUTPUT` rules as my defaults go with `iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT`. Meaning that I trust what is going out of my box. That may not be a good option, especially in a NAT setup.

**Very important note:** FTPS won't work with such a setup, as the passive port is hidden (encrypted), hence there's no way for `iptables` to guess the good port. See [Changing IPTables to Allow FTP over TLS Using Passive Ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280288/changing-iptables-to-allow-ftp-over-tls-using-passive-ports) and https://serverfault.com/questions/811431/are-my-iptables-for-ftps-with-tls-ok

Answer (score 1):

I am adding an answer because rules should be simple, short, and readable.  The accepted answer has security holes in it, IMHO.

For active FTP, all that is needed is:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
```

And if one wants passive FTP, one needs to add:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

From the iptables-extensions manual pages:

> RELATED
> The  packet is starting a new connection, but is associated with an existing connection, such as an FTP
> data transfer or an ICMP error.

But, as remarked by @jakob the kernel needs this configuration:

```
sudo sysctl net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper=1
```