# FTP and iptables. Connection fails but ports are open

Tags: iptables, firewall, ftp, proftpd

I installed proftp on my machine.

With iptables disabled I can connect to the machine, using ftp-client or telnet. 
With iptables connection fails - telnet says "Connection failed"

```
# works
telnet 192.10.10.11 22 

# connection failed
telnet 192.19.10.11 20
telnet 192.19.10.11 21
```

I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400672/linux-bash-setting-iptables-rules-to-allow-both-active-and-passive-ftp), but it did not help.

Since I do open the Ports 22 and 21,20 the same way they should all be accessable through telnet? But 22 works and 21,20 fail. Any ideas why this happens?

`sudo iptables -L -v`

```
 Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
  100  7136 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
    3   152 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:1010:1012
  586 78898 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   any     anywhere             anywhere
  348 22567 ACCEPT     all  --  tap+   any     anywhere             anywhere
   69 10294 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere
   95 11028 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ftp-data
  354 55626 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    tun+    anywhere             anywhere
  353 26295 ACCEPT     all  --  any    tap+    anywhere             anywhere
    4   392 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

`iptables configurations:`

```
#!/bin/sh

# Flushing all rules
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Setting default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow ssh on Port 22
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT



# Ports for FTP

#Allowing FTP Connections, including passive ports. (proftpd)
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT

# Allowing FTP Connections in active mode, where Data are passed through Port 20
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -j ACCEPT

# Allowing Ports for Passive Mode connection, where Data is passed through ports
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1010:1012 -j ACCEPT




# allow connection via 1194 so that openVpn can use the network adapter
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
# allow connections via openVPN tun and tap interfaces
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tap+ -j ACCEPT


# make sure nothing else comes or goes out of this box
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

Comment: This is a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218563/linux-ftp-iptables-configuration/21218759 und you'll find the answer there.

Comment: The post is about to be closed. Ane there are no right answers yet.

Comment: Skip, please do not cross-post the same Q's on the different SE sites. That's a close reason on most of them. Delete that other SO Q and we can leave this one here.

Answer (score 4):

This was the solution.
I don't know why other configs did not work!

```
# allowing active/passive FTP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED,NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Something else must be at play here, I've found the example on dozens of sites and the order doesn't seem to be a factor, for eg: http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/80, has it similar to my A too.

Comment: How could I find out? I think this would be possible with a huge amount of knowledge about the FTP protocol?

Comment: What FTP client are you using to test this?

Comment: Filezilla, Windows Explorer, XBMC, telnet, Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Did you start `proftp`? There are 2 things that you need to do when setting up a service. You've got the first thing done, with the firewall allowing the ports to be opened. But the telnet would seem to be indicating that nothing is listening on ports 20 & 21.

You can use `netstat` and `nmap` to confirm.

#### netstat

```
$ sudo netstat -tapn -4 | grep -E ':20 |:21 '
```

I don't have FTP running so I'm going to use `sshd` as a stand-in for my example.

```
$ sudo netstat -tapn | grep -E ':20 |:21 |:22 '
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      894/sshd            
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:51560      67.253.170.83:22        ESTABLISHED 5892/ssh            
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:39411      192.168.1.109:22        ESTABLISHED 21079/ssh           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      894/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:48375               ::1:22                  ESTABLISHED 27962/ssh           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:22                  ::1:48375               ESTABLISHED 27963/sshd: saml [p
```

Here we can see the process ID for `sshd`, 894, which is the main `sshd` server on my system.

#### nmap

Nmap is a tool for scanning to see if ports are open on a system, and if something is listening. Where `netstat` works from the "inside", `nmap` works from the outside looking in.

```
$ sudo nmap -sS -P0 192.168.1.20

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-01-19 11:08 EST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.20
Host is up (0.000013s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
111/tcp open  rpcbind

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 11.44 seconds
```

Here we can see that only `sshd` and `rpcbind` are allowed access from the external LAN.

#### iptable rules

Given you're able to connect via FTP when the firewall is down, this would seem to indicate an issue with your rules. Try these instead.

*allow port 21 in/out*

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 21"
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 21"
```

*allow port 20 in/out - active*

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 20"
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 20"
```

*allow port 20 in/out - passive*

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024:  -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow passive inbound connections"
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024:  -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow passive inbound connections"
```

***Source:*** [Iptables to allow incoming FTP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93554/iptables-to-allow-incoming-ftp)

Comment: I added your rules for ports 21, 20 - still cant telnet..

Comment: @Skip - Is proftp listening on the external IP interface or the 127.0.0.1 i/f? Output of `netstat -tapn -4 | grep ":21 "` will reveal this.

Comment: The answer was: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2217/proftpd: (acce

Comment: @Skip - so it's listening on all interfaces. What's the distro? Might be SELinux or AppArmor blocking your server from being accessible.

Comment: Its Raspbian. Consider that the connection with iptables rules flushed - works. With rules listed above it doesn't. Looks for me, as if some cache is not cleared and ports remain blocked as soon as the default policy is configured to block everything

Comment: @Skip - it's likely the new & established states of the connection. Is this kernel module installed? `modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp`

Comment: nope. somehow I found at least a configuration, which allowed me to telnet on port 21, see my post below. Thnx for help!