# iptables blocking incoming FTP traffic 2/3 minutes after being reset

Tags: centos, iptables, ftp

On CentOS 6.6-

At first, iptables was blocking access to my FTP server at all while it was on. After some research I added the lines to

```
/etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

that are suggested in the question [Iptables to allow incoming FTP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93554/iptables-to-allow-incoming-ftp) and it works... for about 2 minutes, then I can no longer connect to my server. If I then

```
/sbin/service iptables stop
/sbin/service iptables start
```

It will work again... for a few minutes. This is infuriating.

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Look at your log files (probably `/var/log/messages`) for clues. Paste back anything interesting. When you say you can no longer connect to the server you mean by ftp not in general right?